# Socket.IO and Websockets per-message compression in Webkit

Tags: javascript, webkit, websocket, socket.io, zlib

How do I enable support of "Sec-Websocket-Extension: x-webkit-deflate-frame" in [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) library for per-message compression? It is implemented in Webkit by [March 2012](http://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/hybi/current/msg09463.html), but I could not find the way to enabling it in Socket.IO. If it isn't supported yet, are there some [RFC1979](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1979.txt) Javascript implementations which could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Socket.IO (0.9.13) doesn't support it AFAIK. I just opened an issue on it here:

- https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/1148